# Straight line in TikZ with 'continued' marking in the middle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm looking to get a line drawn in a way that I've often seen in schematics: ---||---, so a line, interrupted by two vertical bars (like a capacitor sign), the two vertical bars very close by, also slightly slanted to the right. Similarly, the same for an upward line. I have been looking through the tikz manual but I'm at loss how to do this. I tried the `midway` node decoration, but then I don't know how to get the paralle lines that break the path (and are slanted) - `\|` is not want I need.

(The goal is to simulate that things (boxes) to the left of the line are repeated several times along this path).

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's another option using decorations to produce the two requested styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\def\MarkLt{6pt}
\def\MarkSep{3pt}

\tikzset{
  TwoMarks/.style={
    postaction={decorate,
      decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position #1 with
          {
              \begin{scope}[xslant=0.2]
              \draw[line width=\MarkSep,white,-] (0pt,-\MarkLt) -- (0pt,\MarkLt) ;
              \draw[-] (-0.5*\MarkSep,-\MarkLt) -- (-0.5*\MarkSep,\MarkLt) ;
              \draw[-] (0.5*\MarkSep,-\MarkLt) -- (0.5*\MarkSep,\MarkLt) ;
              \end{scope}
          }
       }
    }
  },
  TwoMarks/.default={0.5},
  OneMark/.style={
    postaction={decorate,
      decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position #1 with
          {
              \draw[-] (0,-\MarkLt) -- (0,\MarkLt) ;
          }
       }
    }
  },
  OneMark/.default={0.5}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw[TwoMarks,->] (0,0) -- (0,2);
\draw[TwoMarks] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[TwoMarks,->] (0,0) -- (2,2);
\draw[OneMark,<-] (2,0) -- (2,2);
\draw[OneMark] (0,2) -- (2,2);

\draw[TwoMarks=0.25,->] (3,2) -- ++(2,0);
\draw[TwoMarks,->] (3,1) -- ++(2,0);
\draw[TwoMarks=0.75,->] (3,0) -- ++(2,0);

\draw[OneMark=0.25,->] (6,2) -- ++(2,0);
\draw[OneMark,->] (6,1) -- ++(2,0);
\draw[OneMark=0.75,->] (6,0) -- ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Features:

- Using `\MarkLt` and `\MarkSep` one chan change the line length and separation between lines for the double mark.
- By default, the decorations are placed in the middle of the path, but using `TwoMarks=<value>` or `OneMark=<value>`, the position can be changed.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not very familiar with decorations and styles and ... tikz in general.... If I choose in the application of the decoration an arrow-style, then the two slanted lines also get arrow heads. How would I turn these off?

Comment: @osdf You're welcome! Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @osdf I updated my answer introducing some improvements and new functionality. I thought this new version might be of interest for you.

Comment: Thanks!! I fiddled around with such a paramterization, too, but yours is so much better :).

Answer (score 8):

A `sloped` node could be used with white background and the symbol as contents you want to use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{cont} = [
  sloped,
  node contents={//},
  fill=white,
  inner xsep=.1em,
  inner ysep=0pt,
]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw
    (0, 0) -- node[pos=.5, cont] {} (2, 2)
    (0, 0) -- node[pos=.5, cont] {} ++(2, 0)
    -- node[pos=.5, cont] {} ++(0, 2)
    -- node[pos=.5, cont] {} ++(-2, 0)
    -- node[pos=.5, cont] cycle
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result, that also shows the white background of the continuation nodes:

> [image: Result]

Comment: My fairly recent TexLive (Ubuntu 14.04) does not know the key 'node content'. Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: @osdf Then you have probably TikZ < v3.0. You can then remove the key and add `//` to the empty braces: `\node[...] {//}`.

Comment: Since `pos` is always `0.5`, perhaps a decoration could be more appropriate here?

Comment: @Heiko Thanks, that works. In the schema drawings, the line goes till the slanted symbol. If I understand your approach right, this is not possible here?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It's just a simple example, the position depends on the wishes of the OP. Otherwise, it could be added to the style.

Comment: @osdf The line goes from one point to another. The symbol is then put in the middle of the line on top of it with a white background to get the simulation of an interrupted line.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek yes, correct. The overall goal would be to get something along this example (the second one), http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/fir-filter/, however having the slanted capacitor sign instead of the tiny circles (and only horizontal or vertical lines, no intersections at the symbol)

Comment: @osdf Then creating the symbol via `pic` would be an option, but this is a feature of TikZ 3.0 AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution with @HeikoOberdiek's idea in mind:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[par/.style={sloped,fill=white,inner sep=-.6ex}]
\draw (0, 0) -- node[par]{//} (2, 2)
      (0, 0) -- node[par]{//} ++(2, 0)
      -- node[sloped]{\textbar} ++(0, 2)
      -- node[sloped]{\textbar} ++(-2, 0)
      -- node[par]{//} cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Did not think about negative inner seps, only tried 0.